# Appying Function To All Elements Of A Long List vs Over List's First Element Gives Different Results

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, precision-and-accuracy

So, I have two lists, and a function. If I apply my function to both lists in a "listable" manner, I have one result, but if I apply it to lists' elements one-by-one, in a "map" manner, I get slightly different result.

How do I fix this?

```
a = 71.00428009033203125;
b = 71.5652618408203125;
tstFunc[x_, y_] := 0.04686746379620325 + 0.998597351069296 x - 0.00002667617826545349 x^2 - 1.1147778875484568*^-6 x^3 - 9.545047757044727*^-10 x^4 + 1.9551823847676841*^-10 x^5 - 0.00033229168991462903 y - 4.383544784477607*^-6 x y - 5.960020622382784*^-8 x^2 y - 5.884558939835153*^-10 x^3 y + 2.6085442056704577*^-12 x^4 y + 2.297317388713515*^-6 y^2 - 9.645541773068444*^-8 x y^2 - 9.511441168001075*^-10 x^2 y^2 + 3.4034398709508465*^-12 x^3 y^2 + 1.1686028576733287*^-7 y^3 + 1.1067252598785332*^-9 x y^3 + 9.186247574157861*^-12 x^2 y^3 + 1.4473334726028848*^-10 y^4 + 9.081366085213091*^-12 x y^4 - 6.388659545763774*^-12 y^5;
alist = ConstantArray[a, 1000];
blist = ConstantArray[b, 1000];
tstFunc[alist[[1]], blist[[1]]] - tstFunc[alist, blist][[1]]
```

Delivers a difference:

[image: minute difference]

Note that if lists are not that long, there's no dirrefence in the same calculation:

```
alist = ConstantArray[a, 100];
blist = ConstantArray[b, 100];
tstFunc[alist[[1]], blist[[1]]] - tstFunc[alist, blist][[1]]
```

[image: zero difference]

I don't understand how this works. I need consistancy in my calculations. Please help!

Comment: Strange. `NumberForm[tstFunc[alist[[1]], blist[[1]]], 16]` is 70.72441187221068 and `NumberForm[tstFunc[alist, blist][[1]], 16]` is 70.72441187221067

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Machine precision calculations do not track nor try to control precision. Precision is lost by most calculations and very intensive calculations can lose a lot of precision. You get what you get. Using exact numbers gives exact results:

```
a = 71.00428009033203125 // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
b = 71.5652618408203125 // Rationalize[#, 0] &;

tstFunc[x_, y_] := 
  Evaluate[0.04686746379620325 + 0.998597351069296 x - 
     0.00002667617826545349 x^2 - 1.1147778875484568*^-6 x^3 - 
     9.545047757044727*^-10 x^4 + 1.9551823847676841*^-10 x^5 - 
     0.00033229168991462903 y - 4.383544784477607*^-6 x y - 
     5.960020622382784*^-8 x^2 y - 5.884558939835153*^-10 x^3 y + 
     2.6085442056704577*^-12 x^4 y + 2.297317388713515*^-6 y^2 - 
     9.645541773068444*^-8 x y^2 - 9.511441168001075*^-10 x^2 y^2 + 
     3.4034398709508465*^-12 x^3 y^2 + 1.1686028576733287*^-7 y^3 + 
     1.1067252598785332*^-9 x y^3 + 9.186247574157861*^-12 x^2 y^3 + 
     1.4473334726028848*^-10 y^4 + 9.081366085213091*^-12 x y^4 - 
     6.388659545763774*^-12 y^5 // Rationalize[#, 0] &];
alist = ConstantArray[a, 1000];
blist = ConstantArray[b, 1000];
tstFunc[alist[[1]], blist[[1]]] - tstFunc[alist, blist][[1]]

(* 0 *)
```

Alternatively, using arbitrary precision will use inexact values but track and try to control precision.

```
a = 71.00428009033203125 // SetPrecision[#, 20] &;
b = 71.5652618408203125 // SetPrecision[#, 20] &;

tstFunc2[x_, y_] := Evaluate[tstFunc[x, y] // SetPrecision[#, 20] &];
alist = ConstantArray[a, 1000];
blist = ConstantArray[b, 1000];
tstFunc2[alist[[1]], blist[[1]]] - tstFunc2[alist, blist][[1]]

(* 0.*10^-18 *)
```

Comment: Thank you Bob! OMG, both methods are so much slower than just "calc the list" ((( oh well.